# What is $\sum_n n^6$ series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I went to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001014) but I didn't quite understand the formula for sum of this series. Could someone type it in normal shape and answer me?

and if it's no bother please do this for 7th, 8th, 9th and 10th powers?

Comment: What are the first 3 terms of your sequence? You already know about OEIS, so you are 90% of the way to being able to handle this question yourself.

Comment: 1,64,729,4096,15625,....

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^6 = \frac{1}{42} n (n+1) (2 n+1) (3 n^4+6 n^3-3 n+1)\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k^7 = \frac{1}{24} n^2 (n+1)^2 (3 n^4+6 n^3-n^2-4 n+2)\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k^8 = \frac{1}{90} n (10 n^8+45 n^7+60 n^6-42 n^4+20 n^2-3)\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k^9 = \frac{1}{20} n^2 (n+1)^2 (n^2+n-1) (2 n^4+4 n^3-n^2-3 n+3)\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k^{10} = \frac{1}{66} n (6 n^{10}+33 n^9+55 n^8-66 n^6+66 n^4-33 n^2+5)
$$

Comment: Awesome, ***endorsed!!!*** But where the hell do those formulas come from?

Comment: @RobertLewis: See [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).